# How to initialise empty C.CString in cgo

Tags: go, cgo

What do you think is the best way to initialise a C.CString with length x in CGO? Background: I need a char* of a proper size for a C function parameter, but I suppose following code can be improved:

```
// length = 6
var buffer [6]byte
name := C.CString(string(buffer[:6]))
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(name))
```

or

```
// length = 6
name := C.CString("      ")
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to convert a string, just malloc the size you need:

```
s := C.malloc(6)
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(s))
```

Comment: This makes actually sense, but how do I convert it back to a go string in the end?

Comment: `newString := C.GoString((*C.char)(s))` it is

Comment: @netsplit: yes, you convert the pointer to a `*C.char` if you want to copy the bytes back into a Go string.